# Hidden View Offscreen Only to Display When User Pulls Down

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity whose layout consists of a ScrollView which contains the main layout (we'll call this the "Main View") of the page. The reason I'm using a ScrollView is that the on some smaller screens, the content may take up more vertical space than the screen itself. I would like to add a view to or above the ScrollView that will be drawn off the screen (we'll call this the "Hidden View"), and will only display when the user pulls down when they are already at the top of the ScrollView. Below are examples of what I'm describing:

[Before Scrolling Down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFwkz.png)

[After Scrolling Down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfvIo.png)

Also, to make it more complicated, If the ScrollView is being scrolled to the top, I would like it to stop before the "hidden view" comes into view. I only want the "hidden view" to be displayed when the user pulls down after the ScrollView has already been scrolled to the top (similar to pulltorefresh).

I would also like the user to be able to scroll back up to "re-hide" the hidden view.

I'm not sure the best way to implement this.  I've played around with the pulltorefresh library, but it seems too powerful for what I'm trying to accomplish. Plus, it's not exactly the effect that I'm after. For example, I'm OK with the "Loading..." screen showing after the pulldown, but after that I'd like my "hidden view" to remain on screen until the user pushes it back up. If I can accomplish this using pulltorefresh, that'd be great, but I'm getting lost trying to follow the library's code.

I've also considered simply adding the hidden view to the ScrollView, and using `scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN)` to force the ScrollView to scroll to the bottom. The problem with that is, if the device's screen isn't very small, there is enough room for the "main view" and "hidden view" to be displayed at the same time, and no scrolling is needed. Also, I wouldn't get the effect that I'm after of the ScrollView stopping before the "hidden view" comes on to the screen.

The other option I've considered is to do what I described above, then resize the "main view" to match the device's screen size before forcing the ScrollView to the bottom. But again, I would lose the effect of the ScrollView stopping.

I feel like there has to be an easier or more elegant way of doing this that I'm missing. Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

The way I did it was by listening on when the user had scrolled to the top of the page, then tried to scroll up the page again.  I had to basically communicate between two listeners on the ListView, onScrollListener and onTouchListener.  When the user tries to scroll up when already at the top, a search box appears.  Once they scroll back down it disappears.

Here is the code:

```
lstView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (listIsAtTop() && expose)
                    searchBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                searchBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
lstView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && listIsAtTop())
            expose = true;
        else if (!listIsAtTop())
            expose = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    }
});
```

Helper method to find when the list is at the very top and can't scroll any further:

```
private boolean listIsAtTop()   {
   if (lstView.getChildCount() == 0)
       return true;
   return lstView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
}
```

Then have some static variable expose in the class that is initially set to true.  Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like [this](https://github.com/LarsWerkman/QuickReturnListView) is what you are looking for? It is similar to how google now search box appears when scrolling down

Comment: Sort of, but I would only like the box to appear when at the top of the screen, not any time the list is scrolled down.