# Scrolling is delayed when inflating view

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, runnable, layout-inflater

Hope you can help me, this has been bugging me for quite some time now-

I have an activity that at some point inflates a view which has its own layout and logic behind. This view contains a `ScrollView` which I want to be scrolled down x dp when its shown to the user (I don't want user to actually see the scrolling, I want ScrollView to be at the right position as the view displays). 
Here's what I tried so far:

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scrollView.scrollTo(0, someInnerView.getBottom());
            }
        });
```

I've tried using this code in different parts of my view logic such as `onFinishInflate()` but that doesn't work as the data isn't binded to the view at that point. So I added `OnGlobalLayoutListener` and called the Runnable inside `onGlobalLayout()` which does work but with a short delay which can clearly be detected.

How do I solve this problem? All I want to do is to have some part of my ScrollView hidden when it's presented to the user.

All help appreciated!

**EDIT** : to make my intentions clearer- I want to create something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192693/hidden-view-offscreen-only-to-display-when-user-pulls-down), only that I'm using ScrollView